# Emitting Typescript Data Objects on Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

I have defined a simple `User` class in Typescript as follows

```
export class User {
    constructor(public id: string);
}
```

from my socket.io server I emit a message with an instantiated version of this `User` class, e.g.,

```
var user = new User('billy');
io.emit('MyMessage', user);
```

on my client I listen for my message as follows

```
io.on('MyMessage', (user: User) => {    
    console.log(user); // This prints '[object]'
    console.log(user.id); // This prints 'undefined'
    console.log(user[0].id); // This prints 'billy'
}
```

Data between sockets therefore appears to be sent as an array of objects, the typescript definition for the `emit` method also shows this, i.e.,

```
emit( event: string, ...args: any[]): Namespace;
```

Thus, is the cleanest way for me to use the sent data to use array addressing as shown in the third console log line above, i.e., `user[0].id`, or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you can do

```
io.emit('MyMessage', user, someData, someAnotherData);
```

And when you catch it you get

```
io.on('MyMessage', data => {    
    data[0] // user
    data[1] // someData
    data[2] // someAnotherData
});
```

You can use destructuring to manage it

```
io.on('MyMessage', ([user]: [User]) => {    
    console.log(user.id);
});
```

Comment: Being new to js and ts, the destructuring syntactic sugar is the sweetest thing I've learnt today!